# SQL ENUM is it possible to save few enum values in table

Tags: mysql, sql, enumerator

I need to create a water tourism portal and I am thinking: Is it possible to save in a table some values from enumerable?

For example, track can have different types of boats: kayak, boat, canoe. So the person who creates a track can choose that track is valid only for one of the types or 2 or 3. How can I store this data? I am thinking about enumerator but I am not sure if I will be able to store this data in a table.

Comment: Are you referring to `ENUM` data type?

Comment: ENUM saves the types of a boat and in main table it is value by the data type of that ENUM

Comment: What database are you using? _MySQL_?

Comment: Yes I use MySQL

Comment: If there is a limited number of boat types and this number will not change, then ENUM may be appropriate, but if there is a chance that the number of boat types will change, then I suggest a database table for boat types.

Comment: It is only these boat types for sure, I am still a student and it is a project. I just didn't found info anywhere will I be able to give for a rout few types from enumerator

Comment: There is an example of using ENUM data type in Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.7-en/enum.html) for _MySQL_. `boat_type ENUM('boat','canoe','kayak')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality you're looking for is provided by the SET data type, which lets you assign to a column zero or more elements from a given set of (no more than 64) elements (see [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html)).
Recommendations from [Uueerdo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4104224/uueerdo) still apply, of course.

Answer (score 1):

While there is an ENUM type, I generally recommend against using it. It has some unconventional behavior at times (you can reference values by index, and the data type is not handled well by many APIs), and modifying the list of values requires altering the table structure (which requires rebuilding the table, data and all, behind the scenes).

You are much better off creating a lookup table with the enum int value as an id and a string for the values' names. Your "tracks" table can just reference that, as can whatever interface you provide for users to select a boat type. Using an ENUM would mean you either have to the boat types embedded in code behind the user interface, that you then have to coordinate with the the enum values in the table definition; or querying the table structure, and parsing the data type for the "boat type" field.

*Note: If different types need different handling, it can be very helpful to have a code enum mirror such a lookup table, or rather have a lookup table reflect a code enum, then the lookup table mainly serves to enforce data integrity on the database side, and to aid in displaying the data in a user intelligible way.*

Also, keeping future expansion in mind, if the tourism portal later decide to start facilitating rentals, the boats that can be rented will likely have types; so you either have to duplicate the ENUM, or just reference the same lookup table.